# TypeScript Declaration File: Function in namespace

Tags: typescript, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3 in one of my projects and retrieved the TypeScript defintion file from DefinitelyTyped ([Definition File](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/openlayers/openlayers.d.ts)), but some functions are missing, which I have to manually add in the declaration file. One of them is the `ol.inherits`-functions ([OpenLayers 3 API Reference](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.html)).

I am struggeling defining this function, as the **ol** keyword is used as namespace identifier and I am not able to put a function directly in the namespace.

I also tried to add something like this, but obviously it says *Duplicate identifier*.

```
interface olStatic {
   inherits(childCtor: () => any, parentCtor: () => any);
}
declare var ol: olStatic;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made my own definition file for ol3. I am not sure whether this helps but in my own file I do define the ol.inherits like so:

```
declare module ol {

function inherits(arg1:any, arg2:any);
 ........................
export class Collection<T> {
............................
```